# URLs amigáveis e estrutura de pastas

Tags: php, url-amigável, organização-de-projeto

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema para usuários comuns (estes não precisam de log) e usuários com permissões (cadastrados no banco).

> Vamos supor que o sistema seja para cadastro de números telefônicos e que usuários comuns utilizem desse site para fazer consultas em números, como funcionaria:

Usuário comum acessa `listatelefone.com (index.php)` escolhe sua cidade e o sistema redireciona esse usuário para `cidade.php` através do ID da cidade escolhida.

Procurando oferecer ao usuário URL amigáveis, a ideia seria:

```
www.listatelefone.com/ (index.php)
www.listatelefone.com/Nomedacidade (aqui seria o arquivo cidade.php)
```

> Quanto a parte restrita, supondo que o usuário com permissão possua uma página inicial "restrita" e páginas para cadastrar telefones com upload de arquivos de imagens, qual seria uma boa maneira de organizar isso na URL e no diretório de pastas para que o resultado ficasse `www.listatelefone.com/restrito/` nessa página inicial e consequentemente `www.listatelefone.com/restrito/cadastro`?

Para isso eu poderia criar uma pasta `.../restrita/` e adicionar o arquivo `cadastro.php` ali dentro? ou há maneiras diferentes e mais interessantes de se realizar isso?

Esquecendo apenas as URLs e indo para a parte de organização de uploads  e arquivos de processamento (`valida_form.php` por exemplo) eu pensei em criar uma pasta Upload, onde por exemplo, dentro dessa pasta, teria `.../imgs/cadastro/` (nesta página seria inclusa as imagens do cadastro) enquanto que para guardar arquivos de processamento, seria em alguma pasta como `.../processos/`.

E por fim, os arquivos `.css`, `.js`, entre outros - estes eu pensei em colocar cada um na sua respectiva pasta, por exemplo:

```
.../css/arquivos.css
.../js/arquivos.js
```

- Como faço para ter URLs amigáveis e seguir a estrutura que citei?

Comment: Sua pergunta parece um pouco ampla, e talvez baseada em opiniões - de qualquer modo eu editei para tentar deixar mais clara - se não for essa a sua intenção original, você pode [editá-la](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/215203/edit) e voltar atrás. De qualquer modo, dê uma lida [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sobre como formular boas perguntas. :)

Comment: Ah, e "discussão" não é bem o formato do site - por isso a edição se faz necessária.

Comment: Entendo. 
Nesse caso, já que discussão não é o formato, concordo com a edição e fico no aguardo pelas respostas de qualquer forma, obrigado! ^^